# WP - If network url equals then do something

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, multisite

Hi I am having trouble doing an if state in wordpress. If multisite network url equals then do something

Any help? Thanks

```
<?php
    var $china = "network_home_url()/china";
    if($china === true){?>
       <img src="..">
<?php } else { ?>
       <img src="..">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: In multi site you can check site id and use it for particular flow of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

escape quotes, network_home_url() is php function:

```
var $china = network_home_url()."/china";
```

And for 'if' statement use not *true* but the url itself:

```
    if ($china == "http://somekindofurl.com/china") {
//do code
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I cannot get this working

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ideal solution to compare with whole string.

Instead, you can use `strpos()` in PHP to check whether it contains 'china'

something like

```
$url = 'network_home_url()/china';

if (strpos($url, 'china') !== false) {

    echo '<img src="..">';
    /*this is true*/

} else {

   echo '<img src="..">';

}
```

Full doc [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I cannot get this working

Comment: I answered with respect to your question. This may have errors but I ignored that. I just gave you an idea about the right way of to compare substring. Please post your complete code if you want complete working answer. Thanks